# Would moving my site to a new domain host fix a spam blacklisting?

Tags: seo, domains, ip-address, blacklist

I noticed my domain was listed on the blacklist site, Fabelsources. According to the first paragraph of the information I looked up, it said:

> Someone or something on your network sent spam to the
>   spamsources.fabel.dk nds blacklist. Some networks (in particular in
>   South America and Asia) don't maintain good records in whois, so a
>   very large netblock including your IP might have been included in this
>   list.

Would it make sense that if I moved my domain to a new host, my IP would change and then I could try manually delisting, since it says I can submit a manual delisting request.

I'm assuming that my IP was somehow included in a block of IP's as it suggested could happen. So if I move my site to a new domain host, my IP address would change. Then submitting a manual delisting request would be the next step since it probably won't get relisted again if it's due to some other IP that is in close proximity to mine.

Just in case it matters: No, I haven't sent spam from my site, not even email newsletters. I've practically never used email from that account except to verify opening some accounts.

Comment: "I noticed my domain was listed on the blacklist" - You need to clarify whether it is really your "domain" that is blacklisted or the IP address that you domain points to, as you seem to imply in the rest of the question. I assume the later, but obviously if it is your domain then moving servers is not going to help. Are you on a shared server?

Comment: Well, I checked my domain name b/c the tool asked for the domain name, but, yes, from the info provided by Fabelsources, it looks like it's the IP of my domain that's blacklisted. In which case, it makes sense to pay the extra dollar or buy the IP. And thanks @jimmyobonyo for the SPF info.

Comment: "submitting a manual delisting request" - If you are on a shared hosting account (as you mention in comments below) then someone of authority (ie. the host) will need to submit the request.

Answer (score 2):

In Spam blacklisting , only the IP address is blacklisted and nor content of the website / app , this is mainly an issue in shared hosting servers where a single IP address is shared among different users. If 1 users on the network is sniffed by spam spiders "Spam Detection apps/websites" then all users on the network/shared host using the same IP suffer the blacklisting.

To solve this you should either decide to go for dedicated hosting which is much expensive or ask your current provider to add a dedicaed IP to your server space/package/account which is about 1 US dollar/ month , or alternatively you should buy the dedicated IP and give it to your provider to integrate to your server/package/account.Also you should consider using [SPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) (Sender Policy Framework) to your account.

Shifting hosting to another shared hosting will not solve the problem as you will be repeating  the same cycle over and over again ie you do not know if the shared hosting IP adress is already blacklisted also if not , in future , 1 of users in the shared host might be blacklisted hence suffering the same fate again.

Comment: I checked out my hosting plan (Hostgator) info on dedicated IP addresses. It says: "Linux Shared hosting accounts have only one cPanel, so they are allowed only one dedicated IP. If you choose the dedicated IP, all of your addon and subdomains will use the dedicated IP. Emails will still use the shared IP." Would you agree that the fact that the email will use the shared IP negates (for my purposes) getting a dedicated IP?